# Can't send files using Redux Form

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux, redux-form

I'm creating a webpage for me and I'm working with Redux/Redux Form. My backend is working fine, but I can't figure out how to work on my front-end. I'm not using any library to fetch the image in my front, I just copy and pasted a FieldFileInput and it's working fine.

Here is my PostForm.tsx:

```
    renderInput = ({input, label, meta}: {input: any, label: any, meta: any}) => {
        const className = `field ${meta.error && meta.touched} ? 'error' : ''`;
        return (
            <div className={className}>
                <label>{label}</label>
                <div className="input-group input-group-lg">
                    <input className="form-control"{...input} autoComplete="off"/>
                </div>
                {this.renderError(meta)}
            </div>
        )
    };

    onSubmit = (formValues: any) => {
        //@ts-ignore
        this.props.onSubmit(formValues)
    };

    render() {
        return (
            <form
                onSubmit={ this.props.handleSubmit(this.onSubmit)}
                className="ui form error"
            >
                <div className="create-post-field-two">
                    <Field
                        name="title"
                        component={this.renderInput}
                        label="Enter Title"
                    />
                </div>
                <div className="create-post-field-two">
                    <Field
                        name="body"
                        component={this.renderInput}
                        label="Enter Description"
                    />
                </div>

                <div className="create-post-field-two">
                    <Field
                        name="imageUrl"
                        component={FieldFileInput}
                        label="Enter Image"
                    />
                </div>

                <div className="postButton">
                    <button className="btn btn-outline-secondary">Submit</button>
                </div>
            </form>
        )
    }
}
```

In this page I'm certain that everything works correctly, because I receive all data in my Action.

Here is my Redux Action

```
export const createPost = ( formValues: any) => async(dispatch: any, getState: any) => {
  const { userId } = getState().auth;
  let token = userId

 const headers = {
    // 'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data',
    authorization: `Bearer ${token}`,
 };
  let formData = new FormData();
  formData.append('imageUrl', formValues.imageUrl);

  try {

    const response = await AlleSys.post('/posts', {...formValues, image: formData}, {headers})
    dispatch({type: CREATE_POST, payload: response.data})
    history.push('/')
  }catch (err) {
    console.log("ERROR: Couldn't post for identified user");
  }
};
```

If I uncomment the Content-Type I receive the error ***Error: Multipart: Boundary not found***
in my Back-End.
Here Is a screenshot of my request using insomnia.
[image]

I'm stuck on this for days and I can't figure out how to achieve the file upload in the front-end. Please don't mind the typings, I'll correct later.

Comment: Not that it answers your question, but I just want to make sure you know: You are aware that Redux Form is deprecated by the author since 2019? They have it right on their home page and the npm package. Unfortunately there are still (generally extremely outdated) video courses still teaching it.

Answer (score 0):

I used bodyFormData.append to my form fields in the Redux Action and worked like a charm.

```
export const createPost = ( formValues: any) => async(dispatch: any, getState: any) => {
  const { userId } = getState().auth;
  let token = userId

 const headers = {
    authorization: `Bearer ${token}`,
     Accept: 'application/json',
 };

  const { title, body, image } = formValues;

  const bodyFormData = new FormData();
  bodyFormData.append('title', title);
  bodyFormData.append('body', body);
  bodyFormData.append('image', image);
  
  try {
    const response = await AlleSys.post('/posts', bodyFormData, {headers})
    console.log(response)
    dispatch({type: CREATE_POST, payload: response.data})
    history.push('/')
```